# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8

Tags: java

Why do I get this exception? How to fix it?

```
public class NQueen_Pro {


    // int[] Fitness;

        /*
         * int[] NQueens1; int[] NQueens2; int[] NQueens3; int[] NQueens4;
         */
        int[][] NQueens;
        int[][] CrossOver;
        int[] Fitness;
        int nFitSelected;
        long startingTime ;
        /*
         * int[] CrossOver1; int[] CrossOver2; int[] CrossOver3; int[] CrossOver4;
         */

        Random ran;
        int length;
        
        public NQueen_Pro(int n) {
            
            Fitness = new int[n];

            /*
             * NQueens1 = new int[n]; NQueens2 = new int[n]; NQueens3 = new int[n];
             * NQueens4 = new int[n];
             */

            NQueens = new int[n][n];
            CrossOver = new int[n][n];
            nFitSelected = 40;

            /*
             * CrossOver1 = new int[n]; CrossOver2 = new int[n]; CrossOver3 = new
             * int[n]; CrossOver4 = new int[n];
             */

            length = n;

            startingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ran = new Random();
            while(true)
                genetics();
        }

        public void fillValues() {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
                    NQueens[i][j] = ran.nextInt(length);
            }
        }

        private void genetics() {
            
            fillValues();

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                countFitness(i, NQueens[i]);
            }
            

            ArrangeFromFitness();
            CrossOver();
            Mutate();

            IsDone();
            
        }

        private void IsDone() {
            /*
             * if (IsFit(CrossOver1)) print(CrossOver1); else if (IsFit(CrossOver2))
             * print(CrossOver2); else if (IsFit(CrossOver3)) print(CrossOver3);
             * else if (IsFit(CrossOver4)) print(CrossOver4); else{ System.gc();
             * generics(); }
             */

            int gotFit = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < nFitSelected; i++) {
                if (IsFit(CrossOver[i])) {
                    print(CrossOver[i]);
                    gotFit = 1;
                }
            }
            if (gotFit == 1) {
                System.out.println("Total Time : \"" + ((System.currentTimeMillis()-startingTime)/(float)1000) + "\" Seconds.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

        private void print(int[] Array) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Array.length; j++) {
                    if (Array[i] == j)
                        System.out.print(" Q ");
                    else
                        System.out.print(" - ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        private boolean IsFit(int[] crossOver) {
            // Vertical Checking
            for (int i = 0; i < crossOver.length; i++)
                for (int j = i + 1; j < crossOver.length; j++)
                    if (crossOver[i] == crossOver[j])
                        return false;

            // Diagonal Right Checking
            for (int i = 0; i < crossOver.length; i++) {
                int temp = 1;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < crossOver.length; j++) {
                    if ((crossOver[i] + temp) == crossOver[j])
                        return false;
                    temp++;
                }
            }

            // Diagonal Left Checking
            /*
             * for (int i = 0; i < crossOver.length; i++) { int temp = 1; for (int j
             * = i; j < crossOver.length; j++) { if ((crossOver[i] - temp) ==
             * crossOver[j]) return false; temp++; } }
             */

            // Diagonal Left Checking
            for (int i = 0; i < crossOver.length; i++) {
                int temp = 1;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < crossOver.length; j++) {
                    if (crossOver[i] - temp == crossOver[j])
                        return false;
                    temp++;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        private void Mutate() {

            for (int i = 0; i < nFitSelected; i++) {
                int nMutations = ran.nextInt(length);
                for (int j = 0; j < nMutations; j++)
                    CrossOver[i][ran.nextInt(length)] = ran.nextInt(length);
            }

            /*
             * CrossOver1[mutateIndexBit] = ran.nextInt(length); mutateIndexBit =
             * ran.nextInt(length); CrossOver2[mutateIndexBit] =
             * ran.nextInt(length); mutateIndexBit = ran.nextInt(length);
             * CrossOver3[mutateIndexBit] = ran.nextInt(length); mutateIndexBit =
             * ran.nextInt(length); CrossOver4[mutateIndexBit] =
             * ran.nextInt(length);
             */
        }

        private void CrossOver() {
            int crossOvered = ran.nextInt(length);

            for (int i = 0; i < nFitSelected; i += 2) {
                for (int j = 0; j < crossOvered; j++) {
                    CrossOver[i][j] = NQueens[i][j];
                    CrossOver[i+1][j] = NQueens[i+1][j];
                }
                for (int j = crossOvered; j < length; j++) {
                    CrossOver[i+1][j] = NQueens[i][j];
                    CrossOver[i][j] = NQueens[i+1][j];
                }
            }

            /*
             * // FIRST GROUP 
             * for (int i = 0; i < halfLength; i++) 
             * CrossOver1[i] = NQueens1[i]; 
             * for (int i = halfLength; i < NQueens1.length; i++)
             * CrossOver1[i] = NQueens2[i];
             * 
             * // SECOND GROUP for (int i = 0; i < halfLength; i++) CrossOver2[i] =
             * NQueens2[i]; for (int i = halfLength; i < NQueens1.length; i++)
             * CrossOver2[i] = NQueens1[i];
             * 
             * // THIRD GROUP for (int i = 0; i < halfLength; i++) CrossOver3[i] =
             * NQueens3[i]; for (int i = halfLength; i < NQueens1.length; i++)
             * CrossOver3[i] = NQueens4[i];
             * 
             * // FOURTH GROUP for (int i = 0; i < halfLength; i++) CrossOver4[i] =
             * NQueens4[i]; for (int i = halfLength; i < NQueens1.length; i++)
             * CrossOver4[i] = NQueens3[i];
             */

            /*
             * for (int i = 0; i < NQueens1.length; i++)
             * System.out.print(CrossOver1[i]); System.out.println(); for (int i =
             * 0; i < NQueens1.length; i++) System.out.print(CrossOver2[i]);
             */

        }

        private void ArrangeFromFitness() {

            int[] index = new int[length];
            for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
                index[i] = i;
        
            
            for (int i = 0; i < Fitness.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Fitness.length - 1; j++) {
                    if (Fitness[j] > Fitness[j + 1]) {
                        int temp = Fitness[j];
                        Fitness[j] = Fitness[j + 1];
                        Fitness[j + 1] = temp;

                        temp = index[j];
                        index[j] = index[j + 1];
                        index[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            int[][] tempQueens = NQueens;

            /*NQueens[0] = tempQueens[index[0]];
            NQueens[1] = tempQueens[index[1]];
            NQueens[2] = tempQueens[index[0]];
            NQueens[3] = tempQueens[index[2]];*/
            
            int temp = 1;
            for(int i=0;i<nFitSelected;i+=2){
                NQueens[i] = tempQueens[index[0]];
                NQueens[i+1] = tempQueens[index[temp]];
                temp++;
            }
        }

        /*private void printAll() {
            for (int i = 0; i < NQueens1.length; i++)
                System.out.print(NQueens1[i]);
            System.out.println("    " + Fitness[0]);

            for (int i = 0; i < NQueens1.length; i++)
                System.out.print(NQueens2[i]);
            System.out.println("    " + Fitness[1]);

            for (int i = 0; i < NQueens1.length; i++)
                System.out.print(NQueens3[i]);
            System.out.println("    " + Fitness[2]);

            for (int i = 0; i < NQueens1.length; i++)
                System.out.print(NQueens4[i]);
            System.out.println("    " + Fitness[3]);
        }*/

        private void countFitness(int nth, int[] Nqueen) {

            for (int i = 0; i < Fitness.length; i++)
                Fitness[i] = 0;

            // Vertical Checking
            for (int i = 0; i < Nqueen.length; i++)
                for (int j = i + 1; j < Nqueen.length; j++)
                    if (Nqueen[i] == Nqueen[j])
                        Fitness[nth]++;

            // Diagonal Right Checking
            for (int i = 0; i < Nqueen.length; i++) {
                int temp = 1;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < Nqueen.length; j++) {
                    if ((Nqueen[i] + temp) == Nqueen[j])
                        Fitness[nth]++;
                    temp++;
                }
            }

            // Diagonal Left Checking
            for (int i = 0; i < Nqueen.length; i++) {
                int temp = 1;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < Nqueen.length; j++) {
                    if (Nqueen[i] - temp == Nqueen[j])
                        Fitness[nth]++;
                    temp++;
                }
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] arg) {
            
            new NQueen_Pro(8);
        }

}
```

Comment: Line number for error?

Comment: Do you use the debugger in your IDE?

Answer (score 1):

`nFitSelected` is 40. The size of `NQueens` is 8 by 8. You got your condition wrong in the for loop :

```
        for(int i=0;i<nFitSelected;i+=2){
            NQueens[i] = tempQueens[index[0]];
            NQueens[i+1] = tempQueens[index[temp]];
            temp++;
        }
```

If you let `i` reach as high as `38`, `NQueens[i]` would throw an exception when `i` reaches `8`.

The definitions of the arrays :

```
    public NQueen_Pro(int n) {

        Fitness = new int[n];
        NQueens = new int[n][n]; // 8 x 8
        CrossOver = new int[n][n];
        nFitSelected = 40;
        ...

    public static void main(String[] arg) 
    {
        new NQueen_Pro(8); // the value of n
    }
```

Comment: what is the condition?

Comment: @ameer `i<nFitSelected`

Comment: please write down the true condition where the error is occur

Comment: @ameer - ok you're being a little too needy , Eran basically debugged it for you...

Comment: @ameer I don't know what the correct logic should be. I merely showed you where you have a bug that would throw the exception you put in your question's title. You might have more similar bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Meta-notes: Your code needs better formatting - indentation and removal of commented-out-code.

anyway I like using command line to debug:

[image]

Follow what it saws, you need to import that Random class. Where is RAndom? A google search yields [It is in Util](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). So add in:

```
import java.util.*;
```